# "increasing" the logarithmic energy of certain measures

Tags: potential-theory, integral-operators

Let $0<a<b<1$ and $f\in L^2[0,a]$ be a real-valued function with $\int_0^af^2=1.$ Define its logarithmic energy by  $$\mathcal{E}_a(f)=\int_0^a\int_0^af(x)f(y)\log\frac{1}{|x-y|}dxdy$$
**Q.** Does there exist $g\in L^2[0,b]$ with $\int_0^bg^2=1,$ such that $$\mathcal{E}_a(f)<\mathcal{E}_b(g),$$
where $\mathcal{E}_b(g)=\int_0^b\int_0^bg(x)g(y)\log\frac{1}{|x-y|}dxdy$?

**Remark.** This question is related to [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1751835/strict-inequality-for-logarithmic-integrals) and [(2)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221443/an-extremal-type-problem-on-segments/221505#221505).

Comment: There are smooth functions on $[0,b]$ with unit $L^2$ norm and arbitrarily large energy, so what is the question?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I disagree.  $\sup\int_0^b\int_0^bf(x)f(y)\log\frac{1}{|x-y|}$ taken over all $f\in L^2[0,b]$ with $\|f\|_2=1$ is the operator norm of a Hilbert-Scmhidt operator. So it is indeed finite.

Comment: But the norm of this operator will be very big if $b$ is small. Your $b$ is not related to $a$, is it?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: No, it will not be large, it's bounded by the HS norm, which equals (the square root of) the $L^2$ of the kernel.

Comment: @Christian Remling: OK, then take $b$ very big:-)

Comment: This question seems almost identical with this one, which you (= OP) answered yourself: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/221443/an-extremal-type-problem-on-segments/221505#221505

Comment: @ChristianRemling I didnt not answer the question on my other post. All I did was to show a trivial statement( which is true for any positive "nice" measure) that one gets $\leq$ if $a<b$. It seems to me that the inequality is strict. Actually the context of this question is as follows: Say $U\subset V$ are two open subsets on a Riemannian manifold equipped with a nice positive measure $\mu$ and let $\mu(V\setminus U)>0$. Does that imply the norm of log. operator (the absolute value is replaced with geodesic distance)  of $U$ is smaller that $V$?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Let $\ell\in(0,1)$, then $$\max_{f\in L^2[0,\ell]\,\, with\,\|f\|_2 =1}\int_0^{\ell}\int_0^{\ell}f(x)f(y)\log\frac{1}{|x-y|}dxdy\leq\ell\sqrt{\log^2\ell-3\log\ell+\frac{7}{2}}.$$

Comment: @BigM: Fine. Now estimate the same from below and you will answer your question.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Thats an approach that I wanted to avoid (since its computational and not much instructive). Using upper and lower bounds I ended up showing the inequality for $a<b$ satisfying $a$<Constat $b$. very interesting but I believe it should hold for any $a<b$. Also I was hoping we could hit it with some potential theoretic methods.